Did renaissance actors learn their parts by heart?

The actors [in renaissance theatre] did not prepare their parts. Instead, a person backstage whispered the lines to the actor just before he was going to say them.
According to Peter May, Headway Culture and Literature Companion Intermediate (B1+), Oxford University Press 2018, p.14.

This statement came as a complete surprise to me, and I wonder if I may have got it wrong linguistically (I am not a native speaker of English). I had always been certain that renaissance actors did learn their parts by heart, and while it seems reasonable that there  were prompters, they would not be there instead of the actors learning their parts, would they? What could be meant by the statement?

As I understand it, in Shakespeare's London in the late 1500s, the company did a different show each night. I don't know how many were in their repertoire, but it seems to have been many. I would expect that this would call for a robust crew of prompters, at the very least. But professional actors would have to pick up their parts pretty quickly if they expected to remain professional.

Some of the unauthorized versions of Shakespeare are very accurate for a character's lines, or a few characters', but inaccurate for the rest.  Most scholars seem to think this means the actor that took that role provided the text, and it would indicate memorization.

@Mary or it could indicate a written part from which the actor had studied the role, possibly without memorizing it.

(A comment, since this isn't a historical answer) This article describes contemporary theatre practice in Germany, where it's usual for a company to have a large number of plays in repertoire at one time (too many for all the company to reliably memorise everything), so having the prompter detectable, even visible on stage, even participating, is regarded as fine. This isn't about the renaissance, of course, but illustrates that a spectrum of practice is possible here.

It seems that actors studied their roles from extracts known, perhaps unsurprisingly, as parts (from Dramatic Documents From The Elizabethan Playhouses, W. W. Greg, 1931):

Generally speaking it may be said that for every piece in the repertory of an Elizabethan theatrical company there must have existed three playhouse documents or sets of documents. First and foremost there was the Book, or authorized prompt copy. ... Next there were the Parts of the several characters, written out for the actors on long paper scrolls, if we may rely on the evidence of the solitary example that has survived. This unluckily is mutilated and has lost any heading it ever had analogy would suggest that, since the play took its title from the hero, it may have been inscribed simply ‘The Part of Orlando Furioso’. It belonged to Edward Alleyn ; another of his rolls may have been headed ‘The Part of the Moore in the Battell of Alcazar’. Last there were the Plots, skeleton outlines of plays scene by scene, written on large boards for the use of actors and others in the playhouse.

Presumably so few of these parts have survived because they were subject to rough use and possibly destroyed in an attempt to protect intellectual property, but their existence definitely supports the premise that actors studied their roles outside rehearsal and were accustomed to reading them in the initial stages of a production rather than repeating what was whispered to them by a prompter. This is only circumstantial evidence that they memorized their parts, but it is hard to imagine that they did not in the absence of any evidence given to support the claim that they didn't.
Also, from Hamlet:

HAMLET  Follow him, friends. We’ll hear a play
tomorrow. Dost thou hear me, old friend? Can
you play “The Murder of Gonzago”?
FIRST PLAYER  Ay, my lord.
HAMLET  We’ll ha ’t tomorrow night. You could, for a
need, study a speech of some dozen or sixteen
lines, which I would set down and insert in ’t,
could you not?
FIRST PLAYER  Ay, my lord.

And from A Midsummer Night’s Dream:

QUINCE  You, Pyramus’ father.—Myself, Thisbe’s
father.—Snug the joiner, you the lion’s part.—
And I hope here is a play fitted.
SNUG  Have you the lion’s part written? Pray you, if it
be, give it me, for I am slow of study.
QUINCE  You may do it extempore, for it is nothing but
roaring.


Do you want to address why/how OP's source (seemingly reputable, published by Oxford) got it so wrong? Or is the source a nobody whose being wrong is not notable?

Right how bizarre.  It seems remarkable this Peter May guy, writing in an OUP text book, could or would make such a HUGE claim/statement, without more being known about this issue.

@nanoman I don't have enough information about the source to form any hypothesis -- much less reach any conclusion -- about why it makes that statement.

What's the source of the first quote?

@Bergi thanks, I forgot to add it, though I remember having done so :-( I will add it in an hour or two.

This is an answer about early modern theatre but the question is about renaissance theatre - while the periods do overlap, do you have any examples from earlier times?

@DaleM can you point to a source that excludes Shakespeare or the late 16th and early 17th centuries from the English Renaissance?  The Cambridge Companion to English Renaissance Drama does not, nor does any other source I've found.

It's not literature. It's a 48 page paperback book written to be sold for too much money to students. https://elt.oup.com/catalogue/items/global/adult_courses/headway/intermediate/9780194529273?srsltid=AfmBOoqJHMrxYIjKz282JGP4XGPxmKamAR4oUu4PY5KDkoi81NcbsjU1&cc=us&selLanguage=en

@Mazura is anyone claiming that it is literature?

This person is called a prompter, prompt, or souffleur.
From the Wikipedia article for prompter:
"The prompter (sometimes prompt) in a theatre is a person who prompts or cues actors when they forget their lines or neglect to move on the stage to where they are supposed to be situated. The role of the souffleur, or prompter, reaches back to the medieval theater. […] [M]ultiple plays are performed in rotation each week, making it challenging for actors to memorize all their lines."

